# Moving project from one computer to another

Tags: python, django

I have a project I built in python 2.7 on one PC. It uses djagno 1.4.5 and some other modules that are kept in site-packages. I tried to copy the contents of Lib\site-packages to the new PC Python install, but I get missing module errors when I try to run manage.py runserver. Do I have to install everything again on the new pc and just transfer the project files?

Comment: That's what I would do.

Comment: Yes, install everything again using `pip` and a [requirements file](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html#requirements-files). You'll appreciate it later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually, you keep a list of your project requirements in [`requirements.txt`](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) and keep the file at the root of your project. Example `requirements.txt` content:

```
Django==1.6.5
lxml==3.3
```

On the new computer, you clone the repository containing the project source code (or get it different way), then install the requirements via [`pip`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) python package manager:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Also, having separate [virtual environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) for every project is basically must have.

---

In order to create the list of requirements from your current python environment (virtual or system-wide), run:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```